# In oracle EPM, In groovy script how we can get User password to do Basic Auth for calling REST API

Tags: oracle, rest, groovy, passwords, basic-authentication

I am using oracle EPM, I want to call REST API to connect to another service and for that to do Basic Auth from groovy script. We need user Id and password to perform basic Auth.
So with hard coded userId and password, I am able to call REST API. But I want to get the runtime(dynamic) userId and password. I am able to get the runtime user but not able to get the password of the user in groovy scrip. Please let me know how we can get the password of user in groovy script in Oracle EPM.

Able to fetch userName with
String loginUserName = ["$operation.user.fullName"]; // This is returning username

String loginPassword = ["$operation.user.password"];  // This is not working as password is not an attribute of User object.
kindly suggest a way to fetch the password so that it can be use for basic Auth.

[groovy script getting used in oracle EPM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmW9a.png)

I tried to fetch the password but not able to fetch.

Comment: normally password not preserved in memory for security reasons.

Comment: Okay. Need to check other way to perform Basic Authentication then.